# Normalizing a wave function in a mixed well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, normalization

So I got this potential and want to solve for the even wavefunctions

[image]

Since it's symmetric around the origin I need only to look at the interval $[0,b]$ and solve for the wavefunction there. The energy is lower than $V_0$ so I will get exponentials in $[a,b]$ and sine and cosine in $[0,a]$.

\begin{cases}
A\cos(kx) + B\sin(kx),  & \text{for }0 < x < a  \\
Ce^{Kx} + De^{-Kx}, & \text{for }a < x < b
\end{cases}

Now I use the requirement that psi needs to be continuous at $a$, derivative contionuous at $a$, zero at the infinite wall and since I only look at half of the potential I need to add the condition that the derivative should be zero at $x=0$ for even functions of $\psi$. If I do this I get

\begin{cases}
A\cos(ka) + B\sin(ka) = Ce^{Ka} + De^{-Ka},  & \text{(Continuity at $x=a$) [1]} \\
-Ak\sin(ka) + Bk\cos(ka) = K(Ce^{Ka} - De^{-Ka}), & \text{(Derivative continuous at $x=a$) [2]} \\
Ce^{Kb} + De^{-Kb} = 0, & \text{(Wavefunction should be zero at the wall) [3]}\\
-Ak\sin(0) + Bk\cos(0) = 0, & \text{(derivative at $x=0$ should be zero)  [4]}
\end{cases}

From [4] one can see that B have to be zero and from [3] I can express $C$ in terms of $D$ but here is where I get stuck. I got two equations that I can use to solve for $A$ now, but I get two different answers depending on if I use [1] or [2]

\begin{cases}
A = \frac{C(e^{Ka} - e^{-Ka+2Kb})}{\cos(ka)},  & \text{If I use [1]} \\
A = \frac{-KC*(e^{Ka} + e^{-Ka+2Kb})}{k\sin(ka)} & \text{If I use [2]}
\end{cases}

Which one am I supposed to use in the normalization? Or are they equal if you just rewrite them in some way?

Comment: Formulae can be typeset with [MathJaX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020) here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've done the algebra correctly, these equations can be solved for a relationship between $k$ and $K$, which should lead to the quantization of energy levels in terms of $a$, $b$, and $V_o$. Then you solve for $C$ in terms of $A$ from either equation (you MUST get the same result with either) and then normalize.

Comment: I get a transcendental equation for the energy, if I solved for the allowed energyvalues numerically with the help of this transcendental equation and then input them into K and k would the two expressions for A be the same?

Comment: I don't know if they will be exactly the same, but within a phase factor they should be. Both equations are true simultaneously, right? You're looking specifically at the even wave functions. BOTH must be true, so you have to get the *same normalization factor* (|A|$^2$ ) whichever one you use if you do the algebra correctly.